# Angular 2 set selected on a select option dropdown

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-forms

I have 2 objects of the type User:

- `users` has the full list of users.
- `selectedUsers` has the `getUsersBySid` that returns a list of users from db

So I just want to mark as selected the users given by the `getUsersById`: `selectedUsers` and i tried this but its not working:

```
<select multiple materialize="material_select" [materializeSelectOptions]="selectedUsers" [(ngModel)]="selectedUsers" name="users"> 
    <option value="" disabled selected>Usuarios</option>
    <option *ngFor="let user of users" [ngValue]="users" [selected]="selectedUsers.id === user.id">{{ user.name }} ({{ user.email }}) </option>
</select>
```

Function that retrieves the users from DB:

```
 getUsersBySid(){
        this.surveyService.getUsersBySid(this.selectedSurvey)
            .subscribe(
                users => {
                    this.selectedUsers = users;
                    console.log(this.users);
                    console.log(this.selectedUsers);
                }, 
                error => {
                    this.alertService.error("error cargar usuarios");
                }
            );
    }
```

Console.log():

users(3 user objects):

```
(3) [Object, Object, Object]
0:Object
id:"1"
name:"administrador"
pass:"21232f297a57a5a743894a0e4a801fc3"
__proto__:Object
1:Object
2:Object
length:3
__proto__:Array(0)
```

selectedUsers(1 user Object):

```
(1) [Object]
0:Object
id:"1"
name:"administrador"
pass:"21232f297a57a5a743894a0e4a801fc3"
__proto__:Object
length:1
__proto__:Array(0)
```

**edit 2:**
If i print both objects i can see that selectedUsers is changing but the dropdown is not marking as selected the `selectedUsers`

```
<select multiple materialize="material_select" [materializeSelectOptions]="selectedUsers" [(ngModel)]="selectedUsers" name="selectedUsers"> 
    <option value="" disabled selected>Usuarios</option>
    <option *ngFor="let user of users" [ngValue]="user">{{ user.name }} ({{ user.email }}) </option>
</select>
Selected: {{selectedUsers}}<br/>
Users: {{users}}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you posted in your question, `selectedUsers` has a list of users from db, you cannot use it  this way as an object `selectedUsers.id`.

you can try with the below options, but first of all, you have to remove `[selected]="selectedUsers.id === user.id"` from your `option` element, since it has some conflicts with `[(ngModel)]`.

**Option1(the first dropdown in plunker)**: bind `user`(object) with [ngValue], then items of `selectedUsers` must keep the exact instance of items from `users` which means you have to compare `selectedUsers` with `users` and push those users with same value from the original `users` list.

**Option2(the second dropdown in plunker)**: bind `user.id` with [ngValue] or [value], then you should set selectedUser to be an array of `user.id`.

**OPtion3(the third dropdown in plunker)**: use **[compareWith](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/SelectControlValueAccessor-directive.html)** which seems the easiest way.

```
<select [compareWith]="compareFn"  [(ngModel)]="selectedCountries">
  <option *ngFor="let country of countries" [ngValue]="country">
    {{country.name}}
  </option>
</select>

// define this function in your component
compareFn(c1: Country, c2: Country): boolean {
  return c1 && c2 ? c1.id === c2.id : c1 === c2;
}
```

refer the below [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/sTMUVnBaLsSo0vRsCbBF?p=preview) for all the above solutions.

Comment: i have edited the question with the objects, sorry for using the term list

Comment: in your plunker the object method is not working, right? you send 2 objects but the selected option is the 1st :/

Comment: @PriNcee I just make an example. bacause the second object has different instances.  check my updated plunker please. sorry, I have just finished.

Comment: @PriNcee the object method works partly for the first item(it keeps same instance with users array) and doesn't work for the second item(keeps different instances, and this is just for example to showing differences to you). Hope it'll help.  :)

Comment: Im trying the 3rd solution, thank u so much @Pengyy but ive got that error: Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'compareWith' since it isn't a known property of 'select' did i forgot something?

Comment: @PriNcee you have to add `FormsModule` to your NgModule's import part. Don't forget to import `FormsModule` from `@angular/forms`.

Comment: Im still having the same problem, `FormsModule` is in `my app.module.ts` (im using angular-cli)

Comment: @PriNcee wait a moment, I'll try with my local environment. BTW, what's your version of angular.

Comment: @PriNcee I have confirmed with angular 4.1.0. and it works as excepted.

Comment: thats it, im seeing that i installed angular-cli beta that comes with angular 2 not 4... ill upgrade asap!! thanks!!

Comment: Option 3 worked for me while I was trying to use multiselect of angular2-materialize.