# How to set the selected item for a <select> when the type is an Object?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a class named `Session` defined as follows:

```
class Session {
  constructor(
    public id: string,
    public title: string
  ) {}
}
```

I created some instances of the class and exported them:

```
export const LocalSession = new Session("local", "Local Session");
export const RemoteSession = new Session("remote", "Remote Session");
```

I also created a list of the instances and exported it:

```
export const Sessions = [
  LocalSession,
  RemoteSession
];
```

I have a component that uses the list and allows the user to select a session:

```
import { RemoteSession, Sessions } from './session';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-device',
  templateUrl: './device.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./device.component.css']
})
export class DeviceComponent {
  session = RemoteSession;
  sessions = Sessions;
}
```

A `<select>` is used to choose the session:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="session">
  <option *ngFor="let s of sessions" [value]="s">{{ s.title }}</option>
</select>
```

However, upon loading the page in a browser, I find that `LocalSession` is always selected by default instead of `RemoteSession`. Using Chrome's Inspector reveals that every `<option>` has a `value` of `[object Object]`.

If I change the `value` attribute to:

```
[value]="s.id"
```

...then *no* item is selected by default. I would have to also change `Sessions` so that it contained a list of IDs instead of instances. I would like `Sessions` to remain a list of instances if at all possible. How can I set the default selection while still using instances everywhere?

Comment: If you want to bind the full object I think you're looking for `[ngValue]`: `[ngValue]="s"`.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44044746/selected-of-select-doesnt-work-as-excepted-in-angular2 or  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44042797/angular-2-set-selected-on-a-select-option-dropdown/44043801#44043801

Comment: @developer033 no, good idea! That seems to work.